# reverse of a number php error

Tags: php, numbers, reverse

```
<?php

$revs=0;
$no=123;
while($no!=0)
{
$revs = $revs*10;
$revs = $revs +( $revs%10);
$no = ($no/10);
}
echo revs;

?>
```

The code written above doesn't work it shows following error

> "Notice: Use of undefined constant revs - assumed 'revs' in
>   /opt/lampp/htdocs/testprojct/proj.php on line 26

Comment: Besides your syntax error you have 2 little logical errors: 1) `($revs%10)` must be `($no%10)`, since you want the last digit from your number and not from the reversed one 2) `$no = ($no/10);` You must cast the result to an int, so your loop actually stops, e.g. `$no = (int)($no/10);`

Comment: You just missed `$` sign when you are `echo`ing.. change `echo revs;` to `echo $revs;`

Comment: `echo implode('', array_reverse(str_split($no)));`

Answer (score 2):

You just forgot the $ in front of revs where you echo it.